# SVM not working with android studio

Tags: android, virtualization

New android developer here.  I recently bought a new computer, AMD 8320 3.5GHZ and I have 16gb of ram running windows 10.  I've turned on my virtualization in bios but android studio is saying my CPU does not support SVM which I know it does after googling it and using an utility tool that double checked it for me.

my emulator does come up and does work, but it's very laggy.  Am I doing something wrong since my android studio is saying my CPU doesn't support SVM?

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the Android studio site: 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator

> For best performance with Android Emulator 2.0, your system should
>   meet the following specifications: Windows: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality. AMD and Intel Atom processors do not support
>   VT-x virtual machine acceleration. Linux: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality or AMD processors with support for AMD
>   Virtualization™ (AMD-V™) 64-bit Operating Systems.

I would suggest to use an ARM image for the emulator instead of an Intel image. This would not require the use of HAXM nor VT-x.

Comment: thank you for the response.  I'm currently using the ARM image but it's mentioned that it is 10x slower.  Is that correct?